# For each children in element with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

I have this function in "browser" javascript that gets me some data from a table:

```
  [...document.getElementById("myTable").firstChild.children].forEach((tableRow) => {
      if (tableRow.classList.contains("jqgfirstrow")) return;
      var columns = [...tableRow.children];
      [...]
      var name = columns[1].innerHTML;
      var value = columns[2].innerHTML;
      var info = columns[3].innerHTML;
      [...]
  });
```

I tryed to translate this into puppeteer code but I don't know what to do now. I *think* I have an array of the rows but I have no clue how to access the classList of those nodes. I can't find any attribute or function for it. I am also unsure if I can get the innerHTML/Text of the element with `element.nodeValue` and also the children of those rows. Here is my code so far:

```
const tableRows: ChildNode[] = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelector("#myTable")?.firstChild?.childNodes;
    if (!nodes) return [];
    return Array.from(nodes);
  });

tableRows.forEach((tableRow) => {
    tableRow.classList // Doesn't exist
    tableRow.nodeValue // Does exist but unsure if I get the text with that
    tableRow.children // Doesn't exist
});
```

Comment: Copy your browser code into `evaluate` so that you access the primitive properties in browser context and return serializable objects (JSON stringifiable structures, basically) back to Node. You can't return DOM nodes from the browser and deserialize them in Node.

Comment: You need to switch to evaluateHandle for this